# Eight duplicate google map when zoom out to minmum level(google map v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the sample code from google as below. When I try to zoom out to minimum, there appear about 8 maps. WHat is wrong with it? As my understanding, there should only one world map when zoom out to minimum?  Is there any parameter I can set?
[image]

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoQaaN9DLOjrVigdieAL_a1ZkFapkZ8_Y&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 6,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        map.setZoom(3);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can set max and min zoom allowed...see API